# How to echo gutenberg block programatically?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm curious why this never asked before.

With shortcode its very easy if we want to echo the shortcode programatically for example like this:

```
echo do_shortcode('[best_selling_products]');
```

How to do the same with gutenberg block?
Is there any similar function like:

```
echo do_block('woocommerce/product-best-sellers');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are very close, the equivalent function is [do_blocks()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_blocks/) with an **s**, eg:

```
echo do_blocks('<!-- wp:woocommerce/product-best-sellers {...} /-->');
```

In the example above, you would also need to set any required attributes such as the category. [Render WooCommerce Block 'Product Filter – Attributes'...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845240/render-woocommerce-block-product-filter-attributes-in-code-rather-than-via-b/68846450#68846450) is a more detailed example for WooCommerce.

Any serialized block content string generated by the Editor or yourself can be used in PHP template with `do_blocks()`, eg a posts featured image:

```
do_blocks('<!-- wp:post-featured-image {"isLink":true,"align":"wide", "size:"thumbnail"} /-->');
```

Inside `{...}` are the blocks attributes. If the block has default attributes, they are used if you don't provide them or you can selectively set your own.